# Ошибка:Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, php, html

Собственно появляется ошибка на строке

```
<input type="text" min="0" step="0.1" id="amount" name="amount"   
 class="amountField" 
 onchange=f( "amount", "total", "amount", "price") 
 pattern="^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$">
```

Из-за чего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберните `onchange=f( "amount", "total", "amount", "price")` в кавычки что бы получилось так:

```
 onchange="f('amount', 'total', 'amount', 'price')"
```

Comment: все равно ошибка появляется

Comment: Заменил двойные кавычки на одинарные, возможно конфликт еще в них

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Comment: можно было просто в одинарные завернуть все выражение, а не переделыавть целиком